# How to write two select statements in one query for one result

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, dynamic-sql

How to write two select statements in one query for one result,i want to combine two select statements for one result as avg

Result query like:-

```
select (idcount/days) as avg
```

query1:-

```
select distinct COUNT(id) as idcount 
from employee
where joiningdate between CONVERT(varchar,@fromdate,103) and CONVERT(varchar,@TODATE,103)
```

query2:-

```
select DATEDIFF(d,@FromDate,@todate) as days
```

Comment: use subquery for your result

Answer (score 0):

Try somethink like this

```
;WITH CTE AS(
   SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id) AS idcount 
   FROM employee
   WHERE joiningdate BETWEEN CONVERT(varchar,@fromdate,103) and CONVERT(varchar,@TODATE,103) 
)
SELECT idcount/(DATEDIFF(d,@FromDate,@todate)) AS AV
FROM CTE
```

Comment: Is this possible in Dynamic SQL query?

Comment: Yes this is possible, but you need to take care about concatenating proper values.

Comment: I need to insert this into existing dynamic sql query,where should i start from

Comment: Can't help without seeing your code, better way you ask new question for that purpose.